# getCoordinates() not working in Geocoder-PHP

Tags: php, geocoding

I'm use Geocoder PHP to do geocoding for a project. However, when I run the following code, most of which is identical to that on their website, it does not return anything:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$geocoder = new \Geocoder\ProviderAggregator();
$adapter  = new \Ivory\HttpAdapter\CurlHttpAdapter();

$chain = new \Geocoder\Provider\Chain([
    new \Geocoder\Provider\FreeGeoIp($adapter),
    new \Geocoder\Provider\HostIp($adapter),
    new \Geocoder\Provider\GoogleMaps($adapter, 'fr_FR', 'France', true)
]);
$geocoder->registerProvider($chain);
try {
    $geocode = $geocoder->geocode('10 rue Gambetta, Paris, France');
    print_r($geocode->getCoordinates());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

The error returned by PHP is:

```
Call to undefined method Geocoder\\Model\\AddressCollection::getCoordinates()
```

And I can't figure out what's wrong, even after re-reading the documentation and several demos and tutorials several times.

Comment: May I suggest something simpler? https://ipinfo.io/developers

Comment: @OliverQueen Nice, I might use that somewhere else in the project. However, what I need in this case needs to be a bit more accurate (eg. to wifi or GPS -determined location) than IP-based location.

Answer (score 0):

```
$geocode = $geocoder->geocode('10 rue Gambetta, Paris, France');
print_r($geocode->get(0)->getCoordinates());
```

Use get first, or play with its limit http://geocoder-php.org/Geocoder/

IMO, that first part of the documentation is misleading :(